# Override Template from Controller Prestashop

Tags: templates, controller, overriding, prestashop

Can anyone explain me the getOverrideTemplate method ?
I don't know how can I override it in the Category controller for use a new template if it's a subcategory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use category level_depth in cateory tpl or controller.
ex :

```
public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        if($this->category->level_depth ==2)
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category.tpl');
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category2.tpl');
```